# How I use data in javascript codeigniter from ajax in view

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

```
$.ajax({
    url:"<?= site_url('laporan/data_penjualan/') ?>",
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'JSON',
    success:function(data){
      var abc = data;
    }
});

console.log(abc); // I want to use outside ajax
```

How I use data from db in outside ajax?

Comment: Your answer is here [jquery-how-to-use-the-return-value-of-an-ajax-call-outside-that-ajax-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973681/jquery-how-to-use-the-return-value-of-an-ajax-call-outside-that-ajax-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to either:

A. Use a [promise object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
function getData(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         $.ajax({
            url:"<?= site_url('laporan/data_penjualan/') ?>",
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'JSON',
            success:(data) => resolve(data)
        });
     };
}

getData().then(data => {
    //data is your ajax response
});
```

B. Use a callback function if your website supports browsers that don't support Promise and you don't have a polyfill

```
$.ajax({
    url:"<?= site_url('laporan/data_penjualan/') ?>",
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'JSON',
    success: function(data){
        ajaxComplete(data);
    }
});

function ajaxComplete(data){
    //data is your ajax response
}
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much

Answer (score 0):

you can set your `var abc` before ajax start, then set the val after finishing the ajax, but your `console.log` must using some way to call it after ajax finished because ajax is an asynchronous method.

```
var abc;
$.ajax({
    url:"<?= site_url('laporan/data_penjualan/') ?>",
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'JSON',
    success:function(data){
      abc = data;
    }
});

// call console when you know the abc has been set
console.log(abc);

// Example for waiting by setInterval
// var timer = setInterval(function() {
//    if(abc !== '') {
//       // your code
//       console.log(abc);
//       clearInterval(timer);    
//    }
// }, 1000); // change this to your liking, doesn't really matter
```

Comment: `console.log(abc);` will call before ajax response. So It's not usefull

Comment: so I marked a comment for you to noticed that you need to call the console.log after ajax finished, otherwise you should use setInterval for waiting the ajax finished

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var abc;
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?= site_url('laporan/data_penjualan/') ?>",
        type:'POST',
        async: false,
        dataType:'JSON',
        success:function(data){
        abc = data;
    }
});
console.log(abc);
```